# What is the Use of "this" keyword in java

Tags: java

I saw multiple use of the keyword `this` in advanced java programs and in android java files. Can anybody please explain to me the use of `this`? So I can understand the programming better.

Comment: As with your previous question, please use the search facility before posting.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth ok

Answer (score 0):

As said by Oracle's [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)
:

> Within an instance method or a constructor, this is a reference to the current object — the object whose method or constructor is being called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within an instance method or a constructor by using this.

I would check out the documentation as the this keyword is used often in programming.

Comment: I took the liberty to edit the style of your answer, it's better to use the blokquote when you are quoting a documentation.